# Is any way to force one word responses in DialgoflowCX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

We are checking for a simple negative answer in our intent, but is we use "No" as a training phrase, it matches every input including that word:

- No (negative input, right)
- Of course, no problem (positive input, wrong)

Are we missing something?

Comment: Do you have a "yes" intent as well? If so, why not adding "of course", "no problem" in the training phrases?

Comment: Yes, I can add them, but there are so many possible answers that I wanted to know if I could check for just 'No'

Comment: Best practice is to build "yes" and "no" intents with variations of yes/no. See [best practices, Intent reuse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-design)

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Comment: Yes, that´s the way Dialogflow works, but my question is if there is any way simpler to check for an exact answer than feed the engine with an  unlimited number of the possible positive answers and variations. Probably that's impossible and this is the only way. So I'll wait a few days for others options before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @fmarm, you can try [reusing intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-design#intent-reuse). By reusing an intent, you need not to create different intents for different variations of negative answers and can add variations to negative answers in a single intent.